# connecting Python client to node js server

Tags: python, node.js, sockets, network-programming, socket.io

I am trying to connect my python client to Node JS server,
I want to know how to set up the node JS server to service the Python client.

My Python client is below

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 8888
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print "received data:", data
```

Comment: What is the protocol of your application layer? IMHO the most simple is HtTP

Answer (score 0):

Use `http` module in node.js

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8888, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8888/');
```